# babel-transpiler with rails 5 and es6 not found?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, babeljs

I was attempting to find the simplest implementation to start adding ES6 to a legacy Rails 5 app where I had backed out all the JS and started over with sprockets (From Webpacker) due to issues related to a new theme. That's neither here nor there.

Anyway, when I add the `babel-transpiler` gem, do my `bundle install`, add a simple ES6 file to `app/assets/javascripts`, and try to reference it in the `application.js`, I get the following:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'hello' with type 'application/javascript'                                                                                                                         
Checked in these paths:                                                                                                                                                                                            
  /usr/src/app/app/assets/config                                                                                                                                                                                   
  /usr/src/app/app/assets/images                                                                                                                                                                                   
  /usr/src/app/app/assets/javascripts                                                                                                                                                                              
  /usr/src/app/app/assets/stylesheets                                                                                                                                                                              
  /usr/src/app/vendor/assets/javascripts                                                                                                                                                                           
  /usr/src/app/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/thumbjive-koudoku-1.5.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/thumbjive-koudoku-1.5.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/grape-swagger-rails-0.3.0/app/assets/images
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/grape-swagger-rails-0.3.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/grape-swagger-rails-0.3.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/app/assets/images
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/jquery-rails-4.3.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/formtastic-3.1.5/app/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-5.1.4/lib/assets/compiled
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/assets/compiled):
    167:         | © 2018 Copyright:
    168:         a href="xx"  xx
    169:       /! Copyright
    170:   = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    171:   script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.full.js"
    172: 
    173:   / should move this "inline" javascript to its own file

app/assets/javascripts/application.js:19
app/views/layouts/application.html.slim:170:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_slim__4610480053040049878_70056207880740'
```

Here's the `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery-3.4.1.min
//= require rails-ujs
//= require popper.min
//= require bootstrap
//= require mdb
//= require bookmark
//= require voting
//= require hello
```

There is a `hello.es6` file in `app/assets/javascripts`.

The current babel docs link to webpacker for Rails, but then have a separate link out for people using sprockets (that's me!):

https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

But this no longer references babel-transpiler which appears to be long dead.

Is BumbleD with NPM and etc the only/best way now?

Comment: I had to enable es6 on my app at some point and used `harmony` which works fine. In your case what about renaming your file `hello.js` or `hello.js.es6`. or maybe being more explicit in your application.js : `//= require hello.es6`

Comment: renaming to `hello.js` seems to work, but looking at the source in the browser no transpilation ocurred. see https://nandovieira.com/using-es6-with-asset-pipeline-on-ruby-on-rails for the hello.es6 -- I get the alert. But I'm not sure this is a realistic example. Do browsers understand es6 natively now?

renaming to `hello.js.es6` results in the same "not found" error

`//= require hello.js.es6 `

results in the same not found error.

Comment: and requiring the actual name `//= require hello.es6` ? also try to transpile manually fro the console to make sure it is installed properly https://github.com/babel/ruby-babel-transpiler Also the babel transpiler gem is now 5 years old. Maybe you can use `harmony` if nothing works. It was flawless and transparent for me

Comment: Harmony was already enabled. Transpilation is not happening. Require of anything when the actual file extension is `.es6` fails. Note that my OP says effectively "babel-transpiler is wicked old should I do whatever's currently documented?" - my guess is leaning towards yes.

Comment: I was using Dropzone that was compiled by asset pipeline. All that I needed was `gem 'uglifier'` and the following code in config/env/production : `config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)` to work. No babel transpiler. I suggest you try that. If it down't work I can't really help further.